# Unity approaches for automatically setting pivots of each sub-gameobject at base center

Tags: unity, models, pivot

I'm working with some free models online, which don't seem to have pivots properly set for any of its submodels.

- Is there a universal pivot fixer or something
- if not... The center seems correct for each submodel - can the pivot be set to the same local "xz" position but the y coordinate moved to the base of the model? To batch process this, how can one programmatically determine where the base is (assuming lowest y point)

Comment: Presumably you considered using Renderer.bounds for meshes, or Collider.bounds or a physics boxcast from below for objects with colliders?

Comment: I was thinking there might be a completely built-in method for something like this since it seems so common. I guess maybe using free models that were not designed for game use (i.e., bad pivots) is maybe too indie even for Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. In my case the assets were anchored to their Center or so and therefore not properly grounded. The bottom-most pixel was the correct ground. And for some reason the bounds wasn’t correct. No idea why.

So I created a script. I looped through all vertices in the mesh and found the bottommost one. Then I calculated its Y offset from the position of its transform. Then I created a new parent for this mesh’s transform at the same location. Then I adjusted the mesh’s transform’s local position to the offset calculated above.

Answer (score 0):

Take all child objects out of the parent, and place the parent where you want it to pivot (make sure that it is not set to center, but rather pivot[under scene menu]). Then place the children back in.